# Consuming a Lookaround or Ignoring a Non-Capture in a Regex match

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

Consider the following string: `ABC`. I would like to capture the following groups using a regular expression:

```
Group1: AC
Group2: B
```

Both the groups have to be captured using a single regular expression. I do not have control over the code, so sub-matches or capture groups will not help.

I've tried both non-capturing groups and look arounds.

With a Non-Capturing group, the match is still a part of the final result.

```
(?<Group1>a(?:(?<Group2>b))c)
```

Group1: ABC    # Not right as B is part of the match. Group2: B

With a lookaround, Group2 is not consumed and the regex following the look ahead should match the contents of Group2 again which includes it as part of Group1.

```
(?<Group1>a(?=(?<Group2>b))bc)
```

Group1: ABC    # Not right as B is part of the match.
Group2: B

How can I ignore "B" as part of the Group1 match?

Any help on getting around this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Regex engines can't paste together nonlinear submatches into a single match. Any match must be a succession of characters from the original text.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to ignore the non-capturing group from the final match?

Comment: No. The group participates in the match. Whether it captures anything or not is irrelevant.